# How to run a batch script after installation is finished?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, installation

I'm working for a custom installer developed in Visual Studio 2008 (Setup & Deployment > Setup project) for a C# project. I'd like to run a batch file (*.bat) after installation is finished. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm wondering too why VS installer allows me to use there dll exe js vbs only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will have to extend the [Installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.aspx) class and override the [Committed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.committed.aspx) event.

Here is an [example](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/11/06/dotnet-windows-service-installer-and-auto-start-after-installation.aspx). Hope you will be able to find how to run a .bat file in C#.

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class ServiceInstaller : Installer
{
    string strServiceName = "MyServiceName";

    public ServiceInstaller()
    {
        // .............

        this.Committed += new InstallEventHandler(ServiceInstaller_Committed);
    }

    void ServiceInstaller_Committed(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
    {
        // Run your batch file
    }
}
```

[Custom Install Action](http://www.devcity.net/Articles/339/1/article.aspx) is another option. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/759969/custom-install-actions) is a similar thread for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can run a batch file using `cmd.exe`, anyway it is what executes batch files.

Start it this way: `cmd.exe /c <path-to-batch>\batchfile.bat`.

Comment: in the setup for 2010 - there is no way to change the sourcepath of the cmd.exe      this fails when xp location of cmd.exe is in c:\winnt\system32, but windows 7 it is located in c:\windows\system32     i'm stumped

Comment: @pithhelmet `%comspec%` environment variable stores the full path to `cmd.exe`. `%windir%` points to Windows directory, then `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe` correctly points to `cmd.exe`. It will work even if Windows is not on `C:` drive. Since `system32` is listed in `PATH` environment variable, you can omit the full path to `cmd.exe`.