# How to add an Entire folder to Setup Project in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, setup-project

The scenario is, I want to add a folder which contains several Document files containing instructions. How can I select an entire folder and it's contents to be included when Setup is run.

Comment: The links in the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6839320/how-to-run-a-batch-script-after-installation-is-finished may help.

Comment: Look here: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/4522487/786805](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4522487/786805) Much easier then envisioned.

Answer (score 17):

You can drag and drop the out side folder to Setup directory structure. Then it will add all files within it WITH FOLDER STRUCTURE.

But, be careful, once you add the folder with sub, folders, large folders added by mistake requires files by folder to folder delete.

Comment: +1 for the delete hint, it just happened to me and had to start the project from scratch. Ridicuolous lack of functionality...

Comment: This correctly answer the question. Creating the folders and subfolders by hand isn't a viable option.

Comment: What i ended up with to prevent the delete situation, is backup the .vdproj - file before adding the folder, and to remove the folder use winmerge to remove it from the current version (closing visual studio for that process).

Comment: After spending an entire month to find a solution, I finally got this! Thanks a ton! This works.

Comment: to delete: open the project file in the text editor. find the node by "Find text" tool. Use notepad++ to collapse the node or Use brace highlight to highlight start and end brace. delete.

Comment: Adding the folder to the setup project directory didn't do anything for me in VS 2019. Edit: Ah, you have to do it in VS.

Answer (score 6):

You can go to the contents you want in Windows Explorer, copy the items (include sub-folders), then return to visual studio setup project in View->FileSystem and paste these in your desired folder

Comment: This was a better solution for me as I run Visual Studio as Admin, so Drag and Drop from Explorer is not supported.